# Deploying my war file in wildfly 10.0.0 using ubuntu terminal

Tags: ubuntu, wildfly

Kindly tell me the commands for ubuntu terminal to deploy my war file in wildfly server 10.0.0.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running in standalone mode you can drop the file to standalone/deployments folder.
For standalone or domain mode you can deploy the war file with the CLI command
bin/jboss-cli.sh
Use "deploy my.war" and for domain mode you need to add the server-group name, you might use tab-completion for the correct syntax.